# Whether WPF can function as .Net Smart Client App?

Tags: .net, wpf

VS 2008 / 2010

Whether WPF can function as .Net Smart Client App ?

Comment: As a note, after seing Robert's comment below, let's clarify: Smart Client is for web development, Rich Client is for windows client locally installed applications.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia defines a "Smart Client" as an application environment which:

- *delivers applications over a web http
  connection*

  No, but it can be used as a frontend for web services
- *does not require installation (or
  provide automated installation and
  updates)*

  WPF is part of the .NET Framework proper.  If you are running a reasonably up-to-date Windows machine, you probably already have it.  Your application itself will need to be installed somehow.
- *automatically updates without user
  action*

  Not that I know of.  Can be a one-click installation, I believe.
- *has the look and feel of desktop
  applications*

  Definitely has that.

In short, WPF is intended for desktop applications, not web applications.  What you are probably looking for is [Silverlight,](http://www.silverlight.net/) WPF's smart client counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on Smart Client Application.

Smart Client Application will work exactly like Normal Desktop Application - Provided its Data Access Layer is designed through WebService.

From Data Access Layer -> Values are passed to Typed DataSet -> Pushed to Database.

This makes Smart Client Application to work offline which is not possible by normal desktop application.